# Is there a way or a tool to do UI automated testing on Firefox sidebar

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, firefox-addon-sdk, gui-testing

Is there a way or a tool to do UI automated testing on Firefox sidebar? We used Firefox add-on SDK (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) to implement a sidebar with a variety of UI elements (buttons, checkboxes, texts) in Firefox. I am surveying a solution to do UI test automation on this sidebar, but with no luck. For example, Selenium IDE can only record actions performed on a regular web page in Firefox, but not any actions performed on the sidebar in Firefox that implemented by using Firefox add-on SDK. Anyone knows of any solution that can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Add-on SDK comes with a testing framework, here are some docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Unit_testing)

[Here are some example sidebar tests.](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/test/test-ui-sidebar.js)

Comment: Thanks. Although I am sure it is just a unit testing framework.